# Finding pairs out of five

Tags: java

I am having trouble finding pairs in a string of size five. So therefore, there can only be two pairs. For every pair that I have found, I should increase the score by 2 points.
Here is what I have so far, but it is incorrect.

```
  String  temp = "4 5 4 3 3";
  String  tempLine = temp.replaceAll(" ", "");
  String[]  hand = temp.split(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++)
                  {

                      if(hand[i].equals(tempLine.substring(0, 1)) && i !=0 )
                          score += 1;
                      if(hand[i].equals(tempLine.substring(1, 2)) && i != 1 )
                          score += 1;
                      if(hand[i].equals(tempLine.substring(2, 3)) && i!= 2 )
                          score += 1;
                      if(hand[i].equals(tempLine.substring(3, 4)) && i!= 3)
                          score += 1;
                      if(hand[i].equals(tempLine.substring(4)) && i != 4)
                          score += 1;

                  }
```

**EDIT: I am trying to find pairs in the hand that have similar value, for example 4 would be one pair found in this hand**

Comment: Can you give some more code? And some more explanation of what your trying to accomplish!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this fits what you're trying to do.

```
char[] hand = {'a','b','c','b','c'};
/* sort the hand to ensure pairs are next to each other */
for(int x=0;x<hand.length - 1;x++){
    for(int y=(x+1);y<hand.length;y++){
        if((int)hand[x] > (int)hand[y]){
            char temp = hand[y];
            hand[y] = hand[x];
            hand[x] = temp;
        }
    }
}
int score = 0;
for(int x=0;x<hand.length - 1;x++){
    if(hand[x] == hand[x + 1]){
        score++;
        /*if you want to make sure you only get pairs
          add an "x++;" that way it'll skip over the 
          letter you just tested*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort the hand first and then loop though looking for hand[i] == hand[i-1]. Note that you might have to be slightly clever as to not count sets of 3s or 4s twice but this should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Create an actual `Hand` class and don't use `String`s to represent your cards. A `Card`'s rank and suit are suitable candidates for an `enum`:

```
class Card {
  enum Suite { ... };
  enum Rank { ... };

  private final Suite s;
  private final Rank r;

  // ...
}

class Hand {
  private Card[] cards;
  // ...
}
```

And sort the `Card[]` in your `Hand` class which makes it easier to evaluate .

Checkout Oracle's `enum` tutorial which has an example with cards: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html

Answer (score 0):

1) Why aren't you comparing elements of the hand array to **other elements**? You already did the work to interpret the string and create the array data; use it.

2) There are more possible pairs of elements than that. Put down five similar objects in a row in front of you at the computer and try it out for yourself. You should be able to identify ten pairs. You should also be able to identify a pattern to how to find/label the pairs.

Comment: I am trying to find pairs in the hand that have similar value, for example 4 would be one pair found in this hand

Comment: ... And? Your array contains 4 in two different spaces. Compare an element of the array to another element of the array. Don't compare it to part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

This example below is one possibility of how to count pairs. The question is how it should behave (increase the score) in case there are three equal values in the string or array or whatever. Shall this be counted as three pairs or not at all...?

```
123 is in fact three combinations 12 && 13 && 23
111 is in fact three combinations 11 && 11 && 11
```

```
package edu.harris.pairs;

public class FindPairs {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "hello";
    int score = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
          score++;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println(score);
  }

}
```

Hope this helps a bit.